# Does functional programming reduce the Von Neumann bottleneck?

Tags: scala, performance, haskell, functional-programming

I believe (from doing some reading) that reading/writing data across the bus from CPU caches to main memory places a considerable constraint on how fast a computational task (which needs to move data across the bus) can complete - the *Von Neumann bottleneck*.

I have come across a few articles so far which mention that functional programming can be more performant than other paradigms like the imperative approach eg. OO (in certain models of computation).

Can someone please explain some of the ways that purely functional programming can reduce this bottleneck? ie. are any of the following points found (in general) to be true?

1. Using immutable data structures means generally less data is moving across that bus - less writes?
2. Using immutable data structures means that data is possibly more likely to be hanging around in CPU cache - because less updates to existing state means less flushing of objects from cache?
3. Is it possible that using immutable data structures means that we may often never even read the data back from main memory because we may create the object during computation and have it in local cache and then during same time slice create a new immutable object off of it (if there is a need for an update) and we then never use original object  ie. we are working a lot more with objects that are sitting in local cache.

Comment: Although there can be some small optimizations with immutable objects, probably the largest performance boost is due to *lazy evaluation*. Instead of processing each function immediately, functions are only evaluated if we need the result. Although this could *technically* also be achieved by OO programming, etc. it requires a lot of bookkeeping. Personally I would say that using immutabl structures can increase the amount of data, since each time a new oobject is constructed, and the old ones are swapped out of the cache.

Comment: I think this question, whilst perfectly valid, might be better suited for [CS stack exchange](https://cs.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Are you asking specifically about memory in the presence of multicore concurrency? I don't think any of those points can be said to be true in general, but I'm only familiar with the GHC runtime.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem Lazy evaluation seems to be the most Haskell-like feature that TensorFlow makes use of.

Comment: In practice, *GPUs* liberated us, and those run fairly typical, albeit very wide, SIMD architectures. If you're talking about day-to-day CPUs, the fastest languages are imperative ones for fairly fundamental reasons.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Oh man, that’s a classic.  [John Backus’ 1977 ACM Turing Award lecture is all about that: “Can Programming Be Liberated from the von Neumann Style? A Functional Style and Its Algebra of Programs.”](http://www.thocp.net/biographies/papers/backus_turingaward_lecture.pdf)  (The paper, “Lambda: The Ultimate Goto,” was presented at the same conference.)

I’m guessing that either you or whoever raised this question had that lecture in mind.  What Backus called “the von Neumann bottleneck” was “a connecting tube that can transmit a single word between the CPU and the store (and send an address to the store).”

CPUs do still have a data bus, although in modern computers, it’s usually wide enough to hold a vector of words.  Nor have we gotten away from the problem that we need to store and look up a lot of addresses, such as the links to daughter nodes of lists and trees.

But Backus was not just talking about physical architecture (emphasis added):

> Not only is this tube a literal bottleneck for the data traffic of a problem, but, **more importantly, it is an intellectual bottleneck that has kept us tied to word-at-a-time thinking** instead of encouraging us to think in terms of the larger conceptual units of the task at hand. Thus programming is basically planning and detailing the enormous traffic of words through the von Neumann bottleneck, and much of that traffic concerns not significant data itself but where to find it.

In that sense, functional programming has been largely successful at getting people to write higher-level functions, such as maps and reductions, rather than “word-at-a-time thinking” such as the `for` loops of C.  If you try to perform an operation on a lot of data in C, today, then just like in 1977, you need to write it as a sequential loop.  Potentially, each iteration of the loop could do anything to any element of the array, or any other program state, or even muck around with the loop variable itself, and any pointer could potentially alias any of these variables.  At the time, that was true of the `DO` loops of Backus’ first high-level language, Fortran, as well, except maybe the part about pointer aliasing.  To get good performance today, you try to help the compiler figure out that, no, the loop doesn’t really need to run in the order you literally specified: this is an operation it can parallelize, like a reduction or a transformation of some other array or a pure function of the loop index alone.

But that’s no longer a good fit for the physical architecture of modern computers, which are all vectorized symmetric multiprocessors—like the Cray supercomputers of the late ’70s, but faster.

Indeed, the C++ Standard Template Library now has algorithms on containers that are totally independent of the implementation details or the internal representation of the data, and Backus’ own creation, Fortran, added `FORALL` and `PURE` in 1995.

When you look at today’s big data problems, you see that the tools we use to solve them resemble functional idioms a lot more than the imperative languages Backus designed in the ’50s and ’60s.  You wouldn’t write a bunch of `for` loops to do machine learning in 2018; you’d define a model in something like Tensorflow and evaluate it.  If you want to work with big data with a lot of processors at once, it’s extremely helpful to know that your operations are associative, and therefore can be grouped in any order and then combined, allowing for automatic parallelization and vectorization.  Or that a data structure can be lock-free and wait-free because it is immutable.  Or that a transformation on a vector is a map that can be implemented with SIMD instructions on another vector.

#### Examples

Last year, I wrote a couple short programs in several different languages to solve a problem that involved finding the coefficients that minimized a cubic polynomial.  A brute-force approach in C11 looked, in relevant part, like this:

```c
      static variable_t ys[MOST_COEFFS];

 //      #pragma omp simd safelen(MOST_COEFFS)
      for ( size_t j = 0; j < n; ++j )
        ys[j] = ((a3s[j]*t + a2s[j])*t + a1s[j])*t + a0s[j];

      variable_t result = ys[0];

//      #pragma omp simd reduction(min:y)
      for ( size_t j = 1; j < n; ++j ) {
        const variable_t y = ys[j];
        if (y < result)
          result = y;
      } // end for j
```

The corresponding section of the C++14 version looked like this:

```cpp
  const variable_t result =
    (((a3s*t + a2s)*t + a1s)*t + a0s).min();
```

In this case, the coefficient vectors were `std::valarray` objects, a special type of object in the STL that have restrictions on how their components can be aliased, and whose member operations are limited, and a lot of the restrictions on what operations are safe to vectorize sound a lot like the restrictions on pure functions.  The list of allowed reductions, like `.min()` at the end, is, [not coincidentally](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/83360/what-property-of-cons-allows-elimination-of-tail-recursion-modulo-cons/86036#86036), similar to the `instances` of `Data.Semigroup`.  You’ll see a similar story these days if you look through `<algorithm>` in the STL.

Now, I’m not going to claim that C++ has become a functional language.  As it happened, I made all the objects in the program immutable and automatically collected by RIIA, but that’s just because I’ve had a lot of exposure to functional programming and that’s how I like to code now.  The language itself doesn’t impose such things as immutability, garbage collection or absence of side-effects.  But when we look at what Backus in 1977 said was the *real* von Neumann bottleneck, “an intellectual bottleneck that has kept us tied to word-at-a-time thinking instead of encouraging us to think in terms of the larger conceptual units of the task at hand,” does that apply to the C++ version?  The operations are linear algebra on coefficient vectors, not word-at-a-time.  And the ideas C++ borrowed to do this—and the ideas behind expression templates even more so—are largely functional concepts.  (Compare that snippet to how it would’ve looked in K&R C, and how Backus defined a functional program to compute inner product in section 5.2 of his Turing Award lecture in 1977.)

I also wrote a version in Haskell, but I don’t think it’s as good an example of escaping that kind of von Neumann bottleneck.

It’s absolutely possible to write functional code that meets all of Backus’ descriptions of the von Neumann bottleneck.  Looking back on the code I wrote this week, I’ve done it myself.  A fold or traversal that builds a list?  They’re high-level abstractions, but they’re also defined as sequences of word-at-a-time operations, and half or more of the data passed through the bottleneck when you create and traverse a singly-linked list is the addresses of other data!  They’re efficient ways to put data through the von Neumann bottleneck, and that’s basically why I did it: they’re great patterns for programming von Neumann machines.

If we’re interested in coding a different way, however, functional programming gives us tools to do so.  (I’m not going to claim it’s the only thing that does.)  Express a reduction as a `foldMap`, apply it to the right kind of vector, and the associativity of the monoidal operation lets you split up the problem into chunks of whatever size you want and combine the pieces later.  Make an operation a `map` rather than a fold, on a data structure other than a singly-linked list, and it can be automatically parallelized or vectorized.  Or transformed in other ways that produce the same result, since we’ve expressed the result at a higher level of abstraction, not a particular sequence of word-at-a-time operations.

My examples so far have been about parallel programming, but I’m sure quantum computing will shake up what programs look like a lot more fundamentally.

Comment: There is nothing intrinsically functional about calling into a framework with optimised routines.

Comment: @Veedrac Agreed, but there is something functional about, say, building an object to represent an expression, limiting it to operations without side effects, and evaluating it lazily.

Comment: I wouldn't say that's a good description of your examples, eg. C++'s STL or Tensorflow, which are both strict and side-effectful.

Comment: Maybe you’d accept expression templates in C++ as a better example (albeit strict)?

Comment: I don’t want to get off on too much of a tangent, since there are both strict and lazy functional languages, but tensorflow can have lazy evaluation.

Comment: I can get where you're coming from with expression templates, but it's quite tenuous; JIT compilation isn't functional programming just because the intermediates are tree-like data structures that get optimised in tenuously-functional ways, so the same surely applies here.

Comment: I’m not saying that C++ has turned into a functional language or anything (although you can use a subset of it for functional template metaprogramming), but would you agree there’s an influence on the language, and it’s in the direction of getting programmers to write higher-level functions? An example of what I was thinking of with the STL would be the limits on what you can do within an `<algorithm>` using a `parallel_unsequenced_policy`?

Comment: A higher abstraction level, sure.

Comment: A higher abstraction level is true, but not what I was thinking of. Backus in ’77 said that the **real** von Neumann bottleneck is that we had to think in terms of sequencing single-word operations. A fold or traversal are high-level abstractions, but they’re still fundamentally sequences of single-word operations. But there are also a bunch of language extensions, motivated by hardware parallelism, that encourage programmers to write algorithms that operate on “the larger conceptual units of the task at hand.” And these limit what functions can do in ways inspired by functional languages.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/164743/discussion-between-veedrac-and-davislor).

Comment: Thanks for putting togethor this useful answer to what is obviously a point of contention, it will certainly help me.